# While loop not executing correctly

Tags: java

I have been trying to execute this code correctly but something seems missing. The program needs to take a string input and check if it is empty. If it is not, then it should check if there are any characters other than alphabets. If yes, it should throw error and again execute the while loop to take another input. If everything is fine, it should exit the while loop and return the string. Not able to understand what is missing. Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Validator
{
    public static String getString(Scanner sc, String prompt)
{
    char temp;
    String s = "";
    boolean isValid = false;
      while (isValid == false)
    {
    System.out.print(prompt);
    s = "";
    s = sc.next();  // read user entry
    sc.nextLine();  // discard any other data entered on the line

    if (s == null || s.equals(""))
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid input");
    else
    {
        check:
    for (int i =0; i<s.length(); i++)
    {
         temp = s.charAt(i);
        if (!Character.isLetter(temp))
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid input. The name should consist of only alphabets");
            break check;
         }
        }
                }
                 isValid = true;
    }
      return s;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you can use break simply like this

```
    if (!Character.isLetter(temp))
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid input. The name should consist of only alphabets");
        break;
     }
```

PS - what was check ?

Comment: `check` is a evil, nasty "label" which is putting the OP back just before the start of the `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

To avoid invalid input, you should use `goto` for `check:` or `continue` statement. But `continue` is preferable.

```
if (!Character.isLetter(temp)){
  System.out.println("Invalid input. The name should consist of only alphabets");
  continue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code like

package com.practice.strings;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Compare {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    getString();
    System.out.println("exit");
}

public static String getString() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    char temp;
    String s = "";
    boolean isValid = false;
    while (isValid == false)
    {
        s = "";
        s = sc.next();  // read user entry
        sc.nextLine();  // discard any other data entered on the line

        if (s == null || s.equals(""))
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid input");
        else
        {
            int i;
            for (i =0; i<s.length(); i++)
            {
                temp = s.charAt(i);
                if (!Character.isLetter(temp))
                {
                    System.out.println("Invalid input. The name should consist of only alphabets");
                    break ;
                }
            }
            if (i == s.length())
                isValid = true;
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

}